# Register Zipkin with Eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery, zipkin

I have an application that is divided into a few microservices (using Spring Eureka project). 
All the services are registered to Eureka Server - so that the communication between the services can be realized through a "Gateway API" (Eureka Server)

The logs produced by the services are reported to a Zipkin server that runs as a separate service. 
All works as expected but when I go to the Eureka dashboard I am not able to see my Zipkin service since it is not registered with Eureka.

Question: Is it possible to register Zipkin with Eureka Server?

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  logs-aggregator:
    container_name: logs-aggregator
    image: maimas/sr-logs-aggregator-service:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 9411:9411

  database-service:
    container_name: database-service
    image: maimas/sr-database-service:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 28017:28017

  gateway-api:
    depends_on:
      - logs-aggregator
      - database-service
    container_name: gateway-api
    image: maimas/sr-gateway-api-service:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://admin:12341234@gateway-api:8081/eureka
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASEURL: http://logs-aggregator:9411/

  user-service:
    depends_on:
      - gateway-api
    container_name: user-service
    image: maimas/sr-user-service:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://admin:12341234@gateway-api:8081/eureka
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASEURL: http://logs-aggregator:9411/
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://database-service/smartrent2

  property-service:
    container_name: property-service
    image: maimas/sr-property-service:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://admin:12341234@gateway-api:8081/eureka
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASEURL: http://logs-aggregator:9411/
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://database-service/smartrent2

  renter-service:
    container_name: renter-service
    image: maimas/sr-renter-service:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 8084:8084
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://admin:12341234@gateway-api:8081/eureka
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASEURL: http://logs-aggregator:9411/
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://database-service/smartrent2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have found your answer by now. But I am posting this for future reference.

Take a look at this [Github issue](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/1870), it basically explains everything and provides a few workarounds.